# Getting the input in table format in Python

Tags: python, database

I have the following text as input:

```
"""Brian, A+
   Kate, B-
   Abe, F
   Derek, A"""
```

I would like to read it in the following format:

```
Name   Grade
Brian   A+
Kate    B-
Abe     F
Derek   A
```

I know how to do it in R, but I was wondering if there's a way of doing it in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would prefer using `dataframe` from `pandas`, one way may be as following:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

input_text = """Brian, A+
                Kate, B-
                Abe, F
                Derek, A"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_text), names = ['Name', 'Grade'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
               Name  Grade
0             Brian     A+
1              Kate     B-
2               Abe     F
3             Derek     A
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned something new.

Comment: @user98235 Great! `Happy Coding.`

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks a lot like data in CSV format, you could use the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

input = """Brian, A+
Kate, B-
Abe, F
Derek, A"""

spamreader = csv.reader(input.split("\n"), delimiter=',')
for row in spamreader:
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

If formatting is important to you, you may use `str.ljust(width)`:

```
In [201]: import csv

In [202]: with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
     ...:     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     ...:     print('Name'.ljust(10), 'Grade'.ljust(10))
     ...:     for row in reader:
     ...:         print(row[0].ljust(10), row[1].ljust(10))
     ...:         
Name       Grade     
Brian       A+       
Kate        B-       
Abe         F        
Derek       A
```